# Strange material "foggy" artifact

Tags: materials, artifacts

Purchased a material pack, and when I apply some of them, they show up with these weird fog-like artifacts. None of my other materials do this.
Same in both Eevee and Cycles.
Please see plane with added material > The cube wasn´t added by me, it just shows up when the material is added to the plane (and the material is not a volume shader).

Any idea what to do?

[image]

Comment: What (kind of) material is? Can Blender find all external assets?

Comment: Suggestion.  Show your material as a Blender Screen capture of the material nodes and relevant material settings.